# abi: cannot use invalid as type array as argument

Tags: go-ethereum, abi, solidity-0.8.x

I am using go-ethereum to deploy a smart contract.
This is how I create the contractABI

```
    contractABI, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(getAbi()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

This is where I get the error.

```
    address, tx, _, err := bind.DeployContract(auth, contractABI, bytecodeBytes, connection, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

I have verified that I have the correct type.

```
fmt.Println("contractABI = ", reflect.TypeOf(contractABI))
contractABI =  abi.ABI
```

This is the compile smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "./openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol"; //<-- path adjusted for local compilation

contract FlashLoan {
    address private owner;
    address private tokenAddress;

    event LoanExecuted(address indexed borrower, uint256 amount);
    event ActionExecuted(address indexed executor, uint256 amount);

    constructor(address _tokenAddress) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    function flashLoan(uint256 amount) external payable {
        // Perform flash loan logic here
        // Make sure to validate the loan amount and execute necessary actions

        // Example action: Transfer ETH to another address
        address payable recipient = payable(owner);
        recipient.transfer(amount);

        // Example action: Transfer ERC20 tokens to another address
        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(owner, amount);

        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Loan amount not repaid");

        emit LoanExecuted(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function executeAction(uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        // Perform custom actions using the borrowed amount
        // This function can be called only by the contract owner

        // Example action: Transfer ETH to another address
        address payable recipient = payable(owner);
        recipient.transfer(amount);

        // Example action: Transfer ERC20 tokens to another address
        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(owner, amount);

        emit ActionExecuted(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function getBalance() external view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

I use Docker to compile the contract with these commands.

```
docker run -v /home/mypath/contracts:/sources ethereum/solc:0.8.4 --allow-paths=/sources/solc -o /sources/abi --optimize --overwrite --abi --bin /sources/solc/FlashLoan.sol
Compiler run successful. Artifact(s) can be found in directory /sources/abi.
docker run --rm -v /home/mypath/contracts:/sources ethereum/client-go:alltools-latest abigen --abi /sources/abi/FlashLoan.abi --pkg=api --type=FlashLoan --out=/sources/api/FlashLoan.go --bin=/sources/abi/FlashLoan.bin
```

I also compiled the same code on Remix and got the same ABI code.
This gives me the contracts ABI.

```
[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_tokenAddress","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"executor","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ActionExecuted","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"borrower","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"LoanExecuted","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"executeAction","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"flashLoan","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getBalance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
```

Any idea what I can try to fix: **abi: cannot use invalid as type array as argument**?